# Pyodbc error using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and ODBC Driver 18

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a **Microsoft SQL Server 2012** from an **Ubuntu Server 22.04** using the Python's library **pyodbc**.

With the following connection string:

```
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<ip>\<instance>,1433;DATABASE=<db_name>;UID=sa;PWD=<db_psw>;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=no'
```

The result when trying to connect is next error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Should we change something in the database server?

Comment: Are you sure you want \ and not `/` in your connection string?

Comment: Actually, if you know the port number for the instance already and you're including that in your connection string then it's not required to include `\instance` and can sometimes be harmful.

Comment: The error message is telling you that it cannot negotiate an encrypted connection because the target server doesn't support TLS 1.2. Since SQL Server 2008 SP3 and beyond support TLS 1.2, if they have [the appropriate Service Packs and/or cumulative updates installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe), this error indicates that the target server is **extremely out of date**.

Comment: As of ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server the `Encrypt` option is no longer a `Yes`/`No` or `True`/`False` option, it is `Optional`/`Mandatory`/`Strict`. Have you tried `Optional`?